# How does CPython implement pop(0)?

Tags: python, cpython

Consider the following example:

```
L = [1,2,3]
print(id(L))
L.pop(0)
print(id(L))
```

This outputs:

```
1196816830600
1196816830600
```

pop(0) removes the left hand element from L. I don't know how CPython does this under the hood and keeps the same id.  But we can see from timings that it is doing a lot more work than pop() does. For example:

```
def popzero(L):
    for _ in range(10**4):
        L.pop(0)
        
def pop(M):
    for _ in range(10**4):
        M.pop()

L = [*range(10**6)]
%time popzero(L)
M = [*range(10**6)]
%time pop(M)
```

This gives:

```
Wall time: 13.2 s
Wall time: 997 µs
```

Is CPython making a new copy of the list and if so, how does it keep the same id? Or is it moving all the elements along by one in the existing list? Or is it doing something else?

Comment: `id(L)` remains same in both the statements because `L` is an instance of list which has been created, also, note that `L` (list) is a mutable object hence we can make changes to it and it wouldn't affect it's `id` as such. However if you do `id(L[0])` in both statements then you'll be able to find the difference.

Comment: This seems to be [pop](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ab383eb6f03896b0ef6634ee3d776344fcb9e5b8/Objects/listobject.c#L1001-L1033) implementation.

Comment: Whatever happens in the internal mechanisms of pop(0), they're internal; they're not going to change the id of the list. It's impossible for something to change the id of the list. If there was *some other* list object with a different id, then L would not be referencing it; it would still be referencing the original list, which has its own original id.

Comment: @TomWojcik can you tell from that how pop(0) is implemented? I am not good at C.

Comment: The id is assigned to the object when it is created, it is the address in the memory of that object

So the id doesn't change when you modify your object

Comment: @Anush just to reiterate what khelwood is saying, it is very important to understand that a method won't be able to change the ID of an object. The ID of an object is *guaranteed to be unique during it's lifetime*. That's the whole point of the `id` function.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes but if it's also guaranteed to be the physical location in memory of the object these things seem to conflict.

Comment: @Anush no, **it is absolutely not guaranteed to be the physical location in memory**. What gave you that idea? The fact that in CPython, `id` returns the the address of the PyObject header is an *implementation detail*. And while it is true, that is not in conflict with what you've posted above at all. Why do you think it is?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks.  If it did have to be the physical local in memory then deleting parts of the list would require you to make a new copy without those parts and then copy them back. This may be exactly what https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ab383eb6f03896b0ef6634ee3d776344fcb9e5b8/Objects/listobject.c#L610 does?

Comment: @Anush no it wouldn't require that. You seem to think that a list is just a primitive array. It isn't. Everything in Python *is an object*. Yes, there *is* an array,  somewhere in the internals of the implementation of that object, and in the case of `pop(0)` it will be `realloc`'d, but that wouldn't affect the ID of the Python object header. Note, when I say everything, I mean everything, `int`, `bool`, `str` etc not just `list`, `dict` etc, *everything*. Functions, classes themselves...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about C but want to share my insight and it'd be too long for a comment.

That's the [pop](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ab383eb6f03896b0ef6634ee3d776344fcb9e5b8/Objects/listobject.c#L1001-L1033) implementation.

If pop arg is the last element in the list, it calls `list_resize` which doesn't seem to be too complicated.

```c
    if (index == Py_SIZE(self) - 1) {
        status = list_resize(self, Py_SIZE(self) - 1);
        if (status >= 0)
            return v; /* and v now owns the reference the list had */
        else
            return NULL;
```

Otherwise [`list_ass_slice`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ab383eb6f03896b0ef6634ee3d776344fcb9e5b8/Objects/listobject.c#L610) is called. It happens it has a comment in it

> /* Because [X]DECREF can recursively invoke list operations on this list, we must postpone all [X]DECREF activity until after the list is back in its canonical shape.  Therefore we must allocate an additional array, 'recycle', into which we temporarily copy the items that are deleted from the list. :-( */

I'd assume that's where the performance is lost, on this temporary allocation.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking two separate questions.

- Why is the list ID the same before and after popping? As @Naman Chikara has explained in the comments, this is because the ID of a mutable object doesn't change even if the object does.
- Why is `pop()` much faster than `pop(0)`? The answer is [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-June/023437.html):

> Here's my guess: pop() removes rightmost list element by shortening
> the length of the list by 1. pop(0) removes leftmost element by
> shifting the rest of the elements one  place left and then shortening
> the length of the list by 1. It is the shifting that is taking a lot
> of time.

As in many languages, it's much easier to add/remove items from the right side of an array than from the left.

Comment: "Here's my guess:" I was hoping someone might know for sure re: pop(0)

Comment: It's obviously the correct answer. The [other](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-June/023438.html) [responses](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-June/023451.html) in the thread back this up.

Comment: Reference to the implementation is really helpful here.